# How much detail to provide with an answer to a valid question?

Tags: discussion, answers

The hardest thing for me on this site is always determining how much detail to hit someone with: do I make it generic and possibly miss the exact point? Or make it specific and in depth, in which case it feels like I am just providing a solution?

There are always factors to take into account (My main two are always: *Is the question genuine? Is the asker seeking an explanation or simply trying to get a pre-made answer?*)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I believe it would help to improve not only my answers but perhaps provide a reference point for everyone who feels in the same position as myself.

In regards to situations where someone is simply looking for a straight up solution to a problem, the choice is easy: either ignore them if they have not put in any reasonable effort of their own or leave a comment with no answer forthcoming.

However, how much detail should one go into when answering a valid question? Should we give a fully worked demonstrable answer or theoretical overview (generally speaking I mean, as sometimes one or the other will be more appropriate based on phrasing of the question).

Comment: the answer marked as a duplicate was in fact not a duplicate: it deals specifically with near-direct requests for solutions rather than a valid explanatory/exploratory question, which is what I was asking about :)

Comment: I agree; I've edited the supposed duplicate to indicate its narrow (non-overlapping) scope. Hopefully you get four more reopen votes. `:)`

Comment: Cheers:)  I should have foreseen a duplicate closing vote when I first wrote it, but as usual my fingers outpaced my brain...so here we are :)